# Element is not found by id in Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
   <li ng-repeat="menu_group in menu.groups | filter: filterForTablet" hs-css="{selected:isGroupUrl(menu_group.url), opened:isGroupOpened(menu_group.id)}" id="nav-group-Report" class="ng-scope opened selected">
        <div class="table-container with-cells">
            <div class="nav-info" hs-gesture="{handler:openGroup, param:menu_group}">
                <span ng-class="menu_group.icon" class="icon-report"></span>
                <span class="ng-binding">Reports</span>
```

What is wrong with the following? 
No error is generated but the element is not found by id from the Snippet above:

var report = element(by.id("nav-group-Report"));

browser.actions().doubleClick(report).perform();

Comment: If no error is generated, then the element was actually found, but the double click had no effect. What is the expected behavior in this case? Are you sure there are no other elements with `id="nav-group-Report"`?

Comment: So, when I try to find it by id, No error and no element found. But when I run with CSS, the element was found the first time and then it does not. I do get a warning : more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .icon-report:    Following is the command that run for CSS

Comment: var report = element(by.css(".icon-report" ));                                                                
browser.actions().mouseDown(report).mouseUp().perform();
browser.sleep(1000);
browser.actions().mouseMove(report).click().perform();

Comment: @alecxe: The expected behavior is to click on a tab called "report"

Comment: Can we find element "Report" using other locators?

Comment: `Can we find element "Report" using other locators?`  Yes, there are several ways to find an element.  Try using `xpath` with this particular example.

Comment: xpath is not as reliable, I like to see if I could do it other ways.